# How to store list of iterators of set container in Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, set

I want to insert key and value in map container. Here my key is only `string` but value is `list< set<string>::iterator >`.

Here is my header file code.

```
using Mypaths = set < string > ;
using Mapdata = map < string, list < set < string >::iterator > >;

Mapdata myMap;
Mypaths paths;
```

Here i want to insert value from one function, In `mymap` key would be normal `string` but value should be `list of iterator of set container` those pointing to different places of `Mypaths` set.

Please give me idea how can i do this. I searched online i have not got any answer related to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What exactly is troubling you? First you fill `Mypaths` set with strings, then you take iterators to your elements and add them to a list. Lastly, add that list to the map with a suitable key.

Comment: @jrok Exactly I have trouble how to take iterators from set value and put them in list. Main thing is how to take iterators reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that I hope will help:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    using Mypaths = set < string > ;
    using Mapdata = map < string, list < set < string >::iterator > >;

    Mapdata myMap;
    Mypaths paths { "left", "right", "up", "down" };

    // Fill a temporary list with iterators...

    list< set<string>::iterator > temp;

    temp.push_back( paths.find("left") );
    temp.push_back( paths.find("up") );

    // ... and then add the list to the map

    myMap["left and up"] = std::move(temp);

    // Or do it directly within the map:

    myMap["right and down"].push_back( paths.find("right") );
    myMap["right and down"].push_back( paths.find("down") );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got idea how's it works. I am getting value of map with key only. I can read map's key and its value size that means list size. But i dnt know how to access this list iterator and get value from set. Can you please update for the same?

Comment: I am using this code :  

`for (auto& item : myMap)
 {
  cout << "File name is " << item.first.c_str() << "\n";
  for (list<set<string>::iterator>::iterator filePathIter = item.second.begin();
   filePathIter != item.second.end();
   filePathIter++)
  {
   cout << " second :  " << *filePathIter << "\n";
  }
 }`

Comment: i have done to print set values also. so ignore my above comment. Thanks a lot